# How to check/enable mod_rewrite on Apache/Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I can't get wordpress permalinks working on my Fedora LAMP server and expect it's due to mod_rewrite issue, but I can't figure out

1. How do I check if mod_rewrite exists/is enabled?
2. How do I install it (yum?) if it's not?

Any help appreciated.  Thanks-

Comment: does "apachectl -l" list mod_rewrite.c ? if so, it was compiled in.

Comment: @stew- no it doesn't.  All it lists are core.c, prefork.c, http_core.c, and mod_so.c.  So does that mean I have to recompile?  That scares me- is there another way?

Comment: no, it still can be added as a module, this just means it wasn't compiled in directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_rewrite is already included in the `httpd` package, and is loaded in the default configuration. Use the `RewriteEngine` directive to enable it as required.

Comment: @Ignacio- Thanks, can you tell me exactly where and how it goes?  Just anywhere in httpd.conf like: "RewriteEngine on" ?

Comment: The best thing to do is to check the Context tag in the documentation. That will tell you where the directive can be used. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine

Comment: Looks like mod_rewrite was indeed enabled, and I didn't need theRewriteEngine directive- Thanks for the help though-

Answer (score 0):

If you installed apache from your distribution then it almost certainly included mod_rewrite, it's just not being loaded.  If you're on a debian-based distribution use `a2enmod rewrite` to enable it, otherwise you'll need to find the

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

(or something similar) line in your httpd.conf file and uncomment it.

If you built apache by hand, then assuming you also built mod_rewrite as a module, the httpd.conf fix applies to you, but if you didn't build mod_rewrite into apache and didn't build it as a module, you're going to have to recompile.

Comment: @DerfK- It's fedora, and "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" already exists...

Answer (score -2):

```
# a2enmod rewrite
```

Does it help?

Comment: that would help with debian (and ubuntu and other derivatives) but not likely on fedora